# ionic serve fail after update file error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

please help me. I am stuck from last week in this error and I did not find any solution. When I update any HTML file then ionic serve stop working and can not reload. please check the attachment.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1XGu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by replacing scripts in `package.json`.

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
    "serve:before": "watch",
    "emulate:before": "build",
    "deploy:before": "build",
    "build:before": "build",
    "run:before": "build"
  }
```